# Laravel Test: Create Data Using Factory In Laravel Unit Test Not Saved And The Model Count Result Is 0

Tags: php, laravel, testing, eloquent, phpunit

I have a stock model and a stockfactory, then I make a test, in my test I make 3 stocks using the stock factory, there are no errors when I run them, but when I count, the result is always 0.

```php
Stock::factory()->count(3)->create();
dd(Stock::count());
```

[image]

`StockFactory.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Stock;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class StockFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Stock::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'stock_qty' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 10000)
        ];
    }
}
```

`stock-migration`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStocksTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('stock_qty')->default(0);
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stocks');
    }
}
```

query logs

[image]

i have made sure that the stock factory works when not in test environment

Comment: Please provide more information about your env, db setup, factory and...

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost i have provided stock factory code and stock table migration

Answer (score 0):

[image]

solved, i forgot that there is a default scope, that's why the count result is 0